# React Prop returning Null as it relies on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, react-props

Hopefully a simply one.

I make an API call in my component which brings down some account information such as AccountUid, Category etc, i use state to set these.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    fetch(feed_url, {
      headers: {
        //Headers for avoiding CORS Error and Auth Token in a secure payload
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_TOKEN,
      },
    })
      //Return JSON if the Response is recieved
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        throw response;
      })
      //Set the Account Name state to the JSON data recieved
      .then((accountDetails) => {
        setAccountDetails(accountDetails);
        console.log(accountDetails.accounts[0].accountUid);
        console.log(accountDetails.accounts[0].defaultCategory);
      })
      //Log and Error Message if there is an issue in the Request
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching Transaction data: ", error);
      });
  }, [feed_url]);
```

This Works perfectly well and it Logs the correct values in my .then when testing it.

The issue however is that i want to pass these down as props. But i get an error that they are being returned as null (My default state).. i presume as they're jumping ahead.

```
    <div className="App">
  <GetAccountName
  accountUID={accountDetails.accounts[0].accountUID}
  defCategory={accountDetails.accounts[0].defaultCategory}
  />
</div>
```

How do i pass the the 2 details im logging as props?? I've tried setting default state to "" instead of null and just get that it is undefined.

Comment: Could you conditionally render your child component only if `accountDetails` is not null?

Comment: Well i dont really want it to conditionally render. The child component will always be rendered i just dont mind if the details being passed down are blank for 0.2 seconds as the call is being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to use conditional render in your child component, so you should try optional chaining

```
<GetAccountName
  accountUID={accountDetails?.accounts?.[0]?.accountUID}
  defCategory={accountDetails?.accounts?.[0]?.defaultCategory}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since fetching is asyncronous, the most common way is to show some loading indicator (like a spinner) & once the data come in, show the component instead.

If you don't need an indicator, you might just return `null`.

The general idea is to manipulate some intermediary states (e.g. `data`, `isError`) based on the promise state.

Check out [`react-query` library example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-query/tree/main/examples/simple) or a lighter abstraction like [`useFetch` hook](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-fetch) to see how they manage it.

Here's a sample implementation of `useFetch` taken from [this article](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/use-fetch):

```js
const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  const [abort, setAbort] = React.useState(() => {});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const signal = abortController.signal;
        setAbort(abortController.abort);
        const res = await fetch(url, {...options, signal});
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
    return () => {
      abort();
    }
  }, []);

  return { response, error, abort };
};
```